# Using one-time in-app purchases and subscription simultaneously

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

Let's say we have an app with dozens of paid tutorials.

Is it allowed to sell each tutorial as a standalone non-consumable product, and simultaneously offer a subscription which unlocks all these tutorials?

Interesting in both iOS and Android platforms.

Comment: On iOS, yes. I imagine it would be on android too

Comment: On Android, yes.